# Lambda function to capture all local variables and iterate over them

Tags: c++, lambda, reflection, metaprogramming, telemetry

All, I am trying to write a lambda function that accepts all local variables by reference and iterates over them to print out the variable name and variable value.  Or is this even possible?

I know with rttr I can get the individual members of a struct, but what I want is to get all in-scope members so that if I add a new var called `int myNewVar`, the lambda will automatically capture it and print its type and value.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

template <typename T>
constexpr auto type_name() noexcept {
  std::string_view name, prefix, suffix;
#ifdef __clang__
  name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
  prefix = "auto type_name() [T = ";
  suffix = "]";
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
  name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
  prefix = "constexpr auto type_name() [with T = ";
  suffix = "]";
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
  name = __FUNCSIG__;
  prefix = "auto __cdecl type_name<";
  suffix = ">(void) noexcept";
#endif
  name.remove_prefix(prefix.size());
  name.remove_suffix(suffix.size());
  return name;
}

int main()
{
   int var1 {1}, var2 {2}, var3{3};
   float f1 {1.1f}, f2 {2.2f};
   char letter {'a'};
   auto myLambdaThatCapturesEverythingLocal= [=] { 
        //For Each Variable that is in scope
        std::cout << "Type is: " << type_name(varIter) << "\n";
        //where varIter is a specific variable that is in scope, print its value.
        std::cout << "Value is: " << varIter << std::endl;
    };
    myLambdaThatCapturesEverythingLocal();

    /*
        myLambdaThatCapturesEverythingLocal should print out
        Type is: int
        Value is: 1
        Type is: int
        Value is: 2
        Type is: int
        Value is: 3
        Type is: float
        Value is: 1.1
        Type is: float
        Value is: 2.2
        Type is: char
        Value is: a
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct X { int a; float b; char c; };` How do you iterate over the member variables of the X struct?

Comment: Clang's `__builtin_dump_struct` can print types and values of the captures, but not their names. That's the best you can get.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. It is theoretically possible that the language could have this feature. But it does not. @Eljay compile time iteration would be possible with templates.

Comment: Basically you want reflection, which is not something C++ has (yet).  There are libraries out there to get reflection like behavior, but I'm not sure if they support this use case.

Comment: Starting down __Lambda capture__ `identifier ...`  _"...2) simple by-copy capture that is a pack expansion..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda and leading to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack will let you know if I return with anything that works.

Comment: @user253751 You mean aggregates only, without member names, like in [PFR](https://github.com/boostorg/pfr)?

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm pretty sure that talking about being able to do `template<size_t... Is> void foo() { [Is...](){ stuff }; }`

Comment: @NathanOliver this compiles `auto l = [=](auto p ...){ return 0; };` now trying to work out what to do with the parameter pack.

Comment: These comments have been helpful!  I did not add anything about print the name of the variable because I already have code that uses the reflection library rttr to print the variable name.  I just need to get a way capture everything and pass it to the rttr functions so that I'm not manually passing each variable and possibly forgetting one, or adding a variable later and forgetting to add it to the telemetry printer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have the library rttr for reflection.  I just need a way to get all the local variables so that I can pass those to the appropriate rttr functions to get their names and values at runtime.

Comment: @RichardCritten So if the lambda compiles down to a parameter pack expansion, how would I then pass all the in scope variables into the lambda?  From there I could do a fold expression to unpack them in the lambda.

Comment: One wrinkle is that `myLambdaThatCapturesEverythingLocal` doesn't currently capture anything.

Comment: @Eljay That is the question, how to make it capture everything.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if the language had reflection then you could also get names.

Comment: So no ways or ideas on how to have a lambda capture all local variables?